# Convert JSON object to an array of strings with jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a JSON object, which contains only strings and other objects:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": {
    "subKey1":"value3",
    "subKey2":"value4"
  }
}
```

I want to convert it to an array of strings by flattening the structure

```
[
  "key1.value1",
  "key2.value2",
  "key3.subKey1.value3",
  "key3.subKey2.value4",
]
```

I'm rather new to jq syntax and so far I managed to achieve only this with help of

```
to_entries | map([.key, .value | if type == "object" then type else . end]|join("."))
```

then I obtain

```
[
  "key1.value1",
  "key2.value2",
  "key3.object"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short alternative:

```
jq '[paths(scalars) as $p | $p + [getpath($p)] | join(".")]' f.json
```

The expected output:

```
[
  "key1.value1",
  "key2.value2",
  "key3.subKey1.value3",
  "key3.subKey2.value4"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `paths` makes the task simple.

```
paths as $p
| getpath($p) 
| scalars
| $p + [.]
| join(".")
```

produces the stream:

```
"key1.value1"
"key2.value2"
"key3.subKey1.value3"
"key3.subKey2.value4"
```

So you'll want to enclose the filter above in square brackets to produce an array.